# Setting range in ShinobiCharts

Tags: charts, shinobi

I'm trying to set the range of my `NSDateTimeAxis` in ShinobiChart, but something goes wrong, my code looks like this:

```
func segmentedControlTapped(sc:UISegmentedControl){

    let toDateString:String = "2015-01-05"
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.formatterBehavior = NSDateFormatterBehavior.Behavior10_4
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    dateFormatter.calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar)
    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0)

    let toDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(toDateString)

    switch (sc.selectedSegmentIndex){

    case 0:
        println("10 years")
        let fromDateString:String = "2005-01-03"
        let fromDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(fromDateString)
        self.xAxis.setRangeWithMinimum(fromDate, andMaximum: toDate)

    case 1:
        println("5 years")
        let fromDate:String = "2010-01-05"
        let d = dateFormatter.dateFromString(fromDate)
        self.xAxis.setRangeWithMinimum(fromDate, andMaximum: toDate)

    case 2:
        println("3 years")
        let fromDate:String = "2012-01-05"
        let d = dateFormatter.dateFromString(fromDate)
        self.xAxis.setRangeWithMinimum(fromDate, andMaximum: toDate)

    case 3:
        println("1 year")
        let fromDate:String = "2014-01-05"
        let d = dateFormatter.dateFromString(fromDate)
        self.xAxis.setRangeWithMinimum(fromDate, andMaximum: toDate)

    default:
        println("something went terribly wrong")
    }

}
```

I know the dates I use exist on my xAxis, but it still won't let me change the range. What is the correct way to do this?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**EDIT**:

I've also tried it this way, but it gives me the error saying:

> Cannot assign to the result of this expression.

The xAxis is not declared using `let` so this remains a mystery to me.

```
    case 0:
        println("10 years")
        let fromDateString:String = "2005-01-03"
        let fromDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(fromDateString)
        var dateRange = SChartDateRange(dateMinimum: fromDate, andDateMaximum: toDate)
        let range = SChartDateRange(dateMinimum: fromDate, andDateMaximum: toDate)
        self.xAxis.axisRange.minimum = range.minimum
        self.xAxis.axisRange.maximum = range.maximum
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try setting the `defaultRange` of your axis instead? You'll then need to reload and redraw the chart.

e.g. something like this:

```
@IBAction func segmentedControlValueChanges(sender: UISegmentedControl) {

    var interval: NSTimeInterval?

    switch (sender.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0: interval = 60 * 60 * 24
        case 1: interval = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7
        default: println("Error")
    }

    let endDate = startDate.dateByAddingTimeInterval(interval!)

    chart.xAxis.defaultRange = SChartDateRange(dateMinimum: startDate, andDateMaximum: endDate)

    chart.reloadData()
    chart.redrawChart()
}
```